# Jasmine testcase for covering link parameter of the directive

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have been working with the jasmine test cases for the directives but with the template parameter where I would directly check the output of the directive however I do not know how to cover the directive with no template section defined. Like the one given below:

```
    appDirective.directive('linkscriptContainer', [ 'config', function(config) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            'value' : '@'
        },
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            //creating custom script tag
            var customScript = document.createElement("script");
            customScript.type = "text/javascript";

            //checking if property value is available in Config object 
            //then reading the attribute value and constructing the src tag
            if (config[attrs.value] != undefined) {
                customScript.src = config[attrs.value];
            }

            //appending the script tag in linkScriptContainer
            elem.append(customScript);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special for testing the `link` function. Once, you `$compile` your `element` and `$scope.$digest()` (just like you do for any other directive), `link` function will be executed by itself.

If your code `var customScript = document.createElement("script");` is not getting covered, you might need to mock that function like this,

```
spyOn(document, "createElement").and.returnValue({});
```

Comment: the var customScript = document.createElement("script"); line of code has automatically been covered. Thanks for the information. I did not know this before. Helpful! :)

Comment: @ApoorvTiwari glad I could help :)